# Can't connect to wired internet

Tags: internet, lan, wired

Okay, so I recently installed Ubuntu on an old laptop and now it won't connect to the internet. When I plug in the Ethernet cord is says connecting and the little icon things moves but after a minute or so it says disconnected and repeats.

Before I installed Ubuntu it worked fine using Win XP so it's not the port or anything and besides, it recognizes the cord is there, it just won't fully connect. I don't have wireless so I;m not sure if that works or not but I can view the networks around my place. Any ideas? I really need to get this working. Thanks.

TL;DR LAN says connecting and then says disconnected.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Answer (score 1):

start the terminal and type

```
gksu gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

File will opened in gedit. It will be empty or should contain

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

In gedit add following lines and save it and close

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and restart the network manager: `sudo service network-manager restart`
It works fine with my case

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sudo restart network-manager
```

Also: a little bit more information of your system would be helpful!

Comment: @user129523: So, did you then successfully restart your network manager by using the command I provided?

Comment: Yeah, I tried the command but it didn't help. I'm still not able to connect.

Comment: Also is there a way I can Update Ubuntu without connection to the internet? Like Update it with a thumbdrive or something? I mainly just want the plugins and stuff to play media such as music and video.