# trouble connecting to internet

Tags: networking, lubuntu

I have a laptop with lubuntu 13.

Usually it's not connected (I don't have wifi atm) but sometimes try to connect it through the wire I use for my main machine.

However, there seems to be a problem with this. Simply connecting the cord does not seem to automatically connect the computer to the internet, and restarting it a few times does nothing either. I have been able to get a connection in the past when I first updated the system and installed all the programs I use, and also subsequently once. The first time it seemed to connect instantly, and the second time only after several reboots. Today I tried to connect it but nothing happened even after some reboots.

I have tried `service network-manager restart` and it didn't work.

So I'm looking for some commands I can run to diagnose the problem and fix it.

Comment: When you say "it does not seem to automatically connect... to the internet," is that after you go to the internet settings and select wired connection?

Comment: @Jeremy What do you mean by "select wired connection"? Under the wired connection window the box for "Automatically connect to this network when available" is and has been checked, if that's what you are asking about.

Comment: I'm not sure what it looks like when an ethernet cable is plugged in, but right now I'm connected to wifi. When clicking on the internet icon, I have a disabled option called "Wired Network." I'm sure that option would be click-able if I had a wired network.

Comment: I don't have that, but there is a grayed out text in the menu saying 'Ethernet Network disconnected'.

Comment: Have you tried `sudo restart network-manager`? Also, anything in http://askubuntu.com/questions/252774/cant-connect-to-wired-internet?

Comment: Yes I had already tried that, I guess I should mention it in the OP.

Comment: Yeah, you should list every single question you've tried (make sure you've tried every answer within those questions, too).